# Styling an indented h4 element in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `h4` element, which I don't really want to change because I want to keep the `h4` styling (**note**: I assume that the question generalises to other `h*` elements and most other elements).

It's a label on a form and I want to indent the label a little
If I forego the `h4` and turn it into a `div` then I can simply apply `col-xs-offset-3` and it gets indented. But if I apply the same class to the element as an `h4` then nothing happens.

I tried wrapping the `h4` in a `div` and applying the class to the outer `div` but that also did nothing.

Naturally I could roll my own styling for the indentation, but that doesn't seem like the bootstrap way?

What is the idiomatic way to achieve this?

Here's the HTML I'm using:

```html
<div id="page-wrapper" data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="sub-row">
            <div class="padded-row col-lg-4">
              <h4>Template</h4>                        
              <div class="col-xs-10">
                <angucomplete-alt input-class="form-control form-control-small col-xs-3"
                                  match-class="valid"
                                  other="attributes" />
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-blue btn-slim" ng-click="reset()">Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code... preferable fiddler...

Comment: bootstrap just exists so that you have a prefab style to go to, it isn't bad to create your own styles to supplement them (unless you're expressly forbidden to do so, i guess)

Comment: @Jesse This is a good point - I guess I really mean "is the a built-in way to achieve this in BS". On the basis that if BS *can* do it for me sensibly then I should use it, but if not then I'm free to go about it anyway I wish. I'm very new to BS, and thus worried about not using it correctly out of ignorance for what it can do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap myself, but my guess would be that whatever styling is being applied for the `col-xs-offset-3` comes before any of the blanket styling for the `h4` in the compiled Bootstrap stylesheet, or that those styles have `!important` rules on them (which wouldn't make much sense for a framework). If you can post a link to a live page with that class applied to the `h4`, we can give you a solution quicker.

Comment: The bootstrap way would be to create a new rule:
.h4-indent {
padding-left: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

The only 'idiomatic' way of using [offset grid columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) is like this:

Container > Row > Column:

[image: Container > Row > Column]

Where all of those classes should be applied to `<div>` elements.  If you want to modify a column, you should attach the class to the new div column and place *all the contents inside of it*.  This provides a structured and semantic approach to your markup like this:

```css
.block { border: 1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 block">
      <!-- Contents Go Here -->
      <h3>Offset Div</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Beyond that, if you just want to indent a particular element, feel free to build your own classes and CSS rules - bootstrap won't help or hurt you in creating additional stylings.